# Having trouble configuring a URL in Django to work with username instead of id (could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

In my Django code, I have a Profile class which basically extends AbstractUser. I wanted the detail view for this user to use the username instead of the userid, and that is actually working perfectly.

In my urls.py, I have `url(r'^profile/view/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$', ProfileDetail.as_view(), name="profile-detail")` and my ProfileDetail class looks like this:

```
class ProfileDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'username'
```

accompanied by this line in my Profile serializer: `url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='profile-detail', lookup_field='username')`.

This all works great. The problem is when I attempt to view all of my user's "Swipes". My Swipe class has a foreign key relationship with my Profile class (and `related_name='swipes'` in this foreign key).

I added this to urls.py: `url(r'^profile/view/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/swipes/$', ProfileSwipesList.as_view(), name="swipe-detail")` where my ProfileSwipesList class looks like:

```
class ProfileSwipesList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SwipeSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Swipe.objects.filter(user = Profile.objects.get(username=self.kwargs['username']))
```

I verified that the queryset is returning the correct thing, a queryset of Swipe objects. In my Swipe serializer, I tried adding a similar line as the one I added in my Profile serializer: `url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='swipe-detail')`.

However, when I try accessing this URL, I get this error:

> Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "swipe-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.

I'm new to Django, so forgive me if the solution to this is obvious, but I'd appreciate any help with how to get this view to correctly show the queryset I'm returning from my list view.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `lookup_field` on `ProfileSwipesList` and add the `lookup_field` to the respective `HyperlinkedIdentityField`.

Edit:

Based on your comment, you need to use a [custom hyperlinked identify field](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields).

```
class SwipeIdentityField(serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField):
    def get_url(self, obj, view_name, request, format):
        # Unsaved objects will not yet have a valid URL.
        if hasattr(obj, 'pk') and obj.pk in (None, ''):
            return None
        url_kwargs = {
            'username': obj.user.username,
        }
        return reverse(
            view_name, kwargs=url_kwargs, request=request, format=format)


class SwipeSerializer:
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='swipe-detail')
```

Comment: Would the `lookup_field` on `ProfileSwipesList` be `'username'` in this case? This doesn't cause any errors but doesn't seem to change anything either. When I add `lookup_field = 'username'` to the `HyperlinkedIdentityField` in `SwipeSerializer`, I get an error since `username` is not a field in my `Swipe` class. Could I do something like `user.username`? Sorry if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Updated the answer.